# InitializeComponent equivalent for xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, initializecomponent

In some of my smoke tests, I'm using [Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to parse the opcodes of my assemblies.  I then perform some operations to validate code quality, etc.  However, I don't really care about generated code in designers because there isn't much I can do about that, so I will exclude the `InitializeComponent` method.  This worked fine for WinForms, but doesn't appear to work for xaml.  In other words, I'm still processing the instructions in xaml (i.e. Events being subscribed to). I know xaml is "compiled" into baml and not IL, but Mono Cecil is apparently still able to get the OpCodes from baml).

I read [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/XAML%E2%80%94Code-Behind_Class) and [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/05/25/Compiled-XAML-_3D00_-BAML-not-IL.aspx) that in xaml, the `InitializeComponent` calls the `Application.LoadComponent` method, so I tried to exclude that as well, but I was still processing the xaml instructions.  I specifically am checking for event handler subscription.

**My Question:** Are there any other "under the hood" methods that are called when compiling the xaml other than `InitializeComponent` or `LoadComponent`?  In other words, how can I distinguish instructions that come from the code-behind (xaml.cs) vs xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, digging through MSDN, I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms618176.aspx) little gem.

Apparently, the IComponentConnector is what handles both the InitializeComponent as well as the Connect (which handles the event subscription).  So there's a little lesson about WPF vs Winforms, events are set up in InitializeComponent.

So, the method to exclude is:

`System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect();`